# How to use requirements.txt to specify different package versions for different python 3 versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Suppose I am using `pip` to install a package `foo` in Python 3. Now suppose that `foo` version 1.0 works great for Python 3.5 or lower, but breaks for Python 3.6 or higher. And suppose that `foo` version 2.0 works great for Python 3.6 or higher.

How can I specify in my `requirements.txt` that pip should install `foo==2.0` if Python interpreter is 3.6 or higher, and `foo==1.0` if Python interpreter is 3.5 or lower?

Comment: I don't know about that, but you could always have `requirements_3-5.txt` and `requirements_3-6.txt` if pip doesn't support it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It realy easy. The solve is [PEP 508 -- Dependency specification for Python Software Packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/). You must use [environment markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers).  This will allow you to specify different versions of packages for different python versions. For example:

```
foo==2.0;python_version>="3.6"
foo==1.0;python_version<"3.6"
```

Comment: Thank you for the PEP link. Relevant section is [Environment Markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers).